# If I define a variable but nothing returns, is this variable non-existent or just empty?

Tags: php

If I define a variable but nothing returns, is this variable non-existent or just empty?

For example, I define my variable here:

```
$nlDribble = get_option('nl_dribble');
```

If it is empty, I echo some code:

```
if (empty($nlDribble)) {
    echo '<a href="'.$nlLogo.'"><span class="fa-dropbox"></span></a>';
}
```

If it exist, I would do something like this:

```
if ($nlDribble) {
    echo '<a href="'.$nlLogo.'"><span class="fa-dropbox"></span></a>';
}
```

Comment: empty, because you just declared it- so it exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable exists, because you have declared it. However, it is empty, or undefined, so if you do something like

```
$a;
echo empty($a); //returns true;
```

or

```
$a="hi";
unset($a);
echo empty($a); //also returns true
```